# want to filter several data in 3 month periode mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

So in this case I want filter buyer who only appear in (jan, feb, mar) in2019 and appear in (apr, may, june) on 2017, and here's my syntax

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    d1.buyer_id,
    d1.tgl
FROM data_2019 d1
INNER JOIN data_2017 d2
    ON d1.buyer_id = d2.buyer_id
INNER JOIN data_2017 d3
    ON d1.buyer_id = d3.buyer_id
INNER JOIN data_2018 d4
    ON d1.buyer_id = d4.buyer_id
INNER JOIN data_2019 d5
    ON d1.buyer_id = d5.buyer_id
WHERE
    MONTH(d1.tgl) IN (7, 8, 9) AND
    MONTH(d2.tgl) IN (4, 5, 6) AND
    MONTH(d3.tgl) NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12) AND
    MONTH(d4.tgl) NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12) AND
    MONTH(d5.tgl) NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12) group by buyer_id;
```

but that was wrong, do you know where it is  wrong?